# Is there a way to embed html code inside tooltips in plotly with R?

Tags: r, tooltip, plotly

I want to embed html code inside the plotly's on hover tooltip.
Here is a working example:

```
plotly::plot_ly(
  type = "pie",
  labels = "A",
  hovertext = '<i>text in italics</i>', # Renders text in italics
  hoverinfo = "text"
)
```

This reprex seems to work perfectly fine, by rendering the text in italics.  However, more complex html code seems to fail to be rendered as html, and is instead rendered as plain text.
In my case, what I want is to embed an image inside the tooltip, like the following:

```
plotly::plot_ly(
  type = "pie",
  labels = "A",
  hovertext = '<img src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg">', # Does not render as html
  hoverinfo = "text"
)
```

A few other values I have tried to use for `hovertext` (or for `text`, for this matter both work the same):

**Values that are rendered just as plain text:**

```
'<div><i>text in italics</i></div>'
'<div><img src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg"></div>',
'<img src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg">',
htmltools::HTML('<img src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg">'),
htmltools::HTML('<div><img src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg"></div>'),
```

To be sure, the first one renders as "<div>*text in italics*</div>" (italics ok)

**Values that make the tooltip not to work at all:**

```
htmltools::img(src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg")
htmltools::div(htmltools::img(src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg"))
htmltools::div('<img src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg">')
```

**Related posts and likely solutions:**

[Hover Events with JavaScript in R](https://plot.ly/r/hover-events/) could at least partially solve the problem (I could go with an image that changes instead of the tooltip showing up); however, this page seems to be outdated.  Also, I don't get how the javascript code is embedded.

[gdlmx solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755712/place-a-chart-in-plotly-popup/36814401#36814401) gives also some ideas that may be helpful.  However, my code must generate a static html output, so I cannot rely on Shiny.

[Bob's Your Uncle seems to find a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044089/r-d3heatmap-shiny-is-there-a-way-to-embed-images-in-d3-tooltip) for d3heatmap, which if I'm not wrong is built over D3 as plotly is. I'm not that familiar with javascript though, and I'm not sure I can follow his code very well, or whether his solution would apply to plotly tooltips as well.

As explained [by Brandon Bertelsen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671958/how-to-embed-an-image-in-a-cell-a-table-using-dt-r-and-shiny?rq=1), `DT::datatable` has a `escape` parameter that can be set to `FALSE`, to avoid escaping html code inside a datatable, thus rendering the html code *inside* the table properly.  As far as I know, plotly doesn't have anything like that. Also, I think datatables is not built on top of D3 (but I'm not 100% sure).

Any ideas about how to solve this?  Thanks so much!

Comment: Looks like `plotly` *"uses a subset of HTML tags"* https://help.plot.ly/adding-HTML-and-links-to-charts/ and it looks like `img` didn't make the cut

Comment: If you are using shiny, it is possible to display the picture outside the plot conditionnaly

Comment: As I said, I need to generate a static HTML document, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot put arbitrary HTML such as `<div>` or `<code>` or `<img>` into the hoverlabels, just simple formatting tags.

The [allowed tags in the source of Plotly.js](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/c1ef6911da054f3b16a7abe8fb2d56019988ba14/src/components/fx/hover.js#L1596) today are `<br>`, `<sub>`, `<sup>`, `<b>`, `<i>`, `<em>`

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in that direction, that's really clarifying. I wonder whether it's possible to override `plainText(s, len)` to accept other tags... or would it require more work than that?

Comment: Unfortunately no: the hoverlabels are not actually HTML, they are translated from HTML to SVG.