# Hover image in plotly r chart in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly, shinyapps

Does anyone here have an example of showing an image when hovered on a plot or any package which can do this? I have tried something but it will show url only but not the image.I know this code is just encasing the URL. How can I build a div to show the image.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

# Data ------------------------------------------------------------------
dt <- data.frame(fruits = c("apple","banana","oranges"),
  rank = c(11, 22, 33), 
  image_url = c(
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521671413015-ce2b0103c8c7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=45547f67f01ffdcad0e33c8417b840a9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=667&q=80',             
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520699697851-3dc68aa3a474?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=ef15aee8bcb3f5928e5b31347adb6173&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=80",                        
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501925873391-c3cd73416c5b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=379e4a0fffc6d11cd5794806681d0211&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80"
))

# img_dt <- dt %>%
#   mutate(img = paste0("<a target='_blank' href='", image_url, "'><img src=\'", image_url, "' height='40'></img></a>")) %>%
#   mutate(link = paste0("<a href='", image_url,"' target='_blank'>","View photo","</a>")) 

# Dashboard ----------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),

  dashboardSidebar(),

  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML(
          "img.small-img {
          max-width: 75px;
          }")
      )
    ),

    plotlyOutput("hoverplot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$hoverplot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      dt,
      x         = ~fruits,
      y         = ~rank,
      type      = 'scatter',
      mode      = 'markers',
      hoverinfo = 'text',
      text      = ~ paste(
        'Species: ', fruits,
        '</br> Creative: ', paste0(
          "<a target='_blank' href='", image_url, "'><img src=\'",
          image_url,
          "' height='40'></img></a>"
          )
        )
      )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: [Not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805423/is-there-a-way-to-embed-html-code-inside-tooltips-in-plotly-with-r). But you can do [that](https://anchormen.nl/blog/data-science-ai/images-in-plotly-with-r/).

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the image in the tooltip? The closest examples I can find allow you to put the image somewhere on the plot - i.e. the top left corner. See: https://plotly-r.com/supplying-custom-data.html#fig:tooltip-image

Comment: @SNT a comment on my below approach would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

As stated by @StéphaneLaurent it's [not possible](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/c1ef6911da054f3b16a7abe8fb2d56019988ba14/src/components/fx/hover.js#L1596) to show an image directly using plotly's hoverinfo.

However, here is a workaround based on the `customdata` argument already mentioned by @mb158127.

This also takes into account the x and y position of the `hover_event`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)

# Data ------------------------------------------------------------------
dt <- data.frame(
  fruits = c("apple", "banana", "oranges"),
  rank = c(11, 22, 33),
  image_url = c(
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521671413015-ce2b0103c8c7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=45547f67f01ffdcad0e33c8417b840a9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=667&q=80',
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520699697851-3dc68aa3a474?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=ef15aee8bcb3f5928e5b31347adb6173&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501925873391-c3cd73416c5b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=379e4a0fffc6d11cd5794806681d0211&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80"
  )
)

# Dashboard ----------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML("img.small-img {
          max-width: 75px;
          }")
  )),
  plotlyOutput("hoverplot"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$hoverplot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      dt,
      x         = ~ fruits,
      y         = ~ rank,
      type      = 'scatter',
      mode      = 'markers',
      hoverinfo = 'none',
      source = "hoverplotsource",
      customdata = ~ image_url
    ) %>%
      event_register('plotly_hover') %>%
      event_register('plotly_unhover')
  })

  hover_event <- reactive({
    event_data(event = "plotly_hover", source = "hoverplotsource")
  })

  unhover_event <- reactive({
    event_data(event = "plotly_unhover", source = "hoverplotsource")
  })

  hoverplotlyProxy <- plotlyProxy("hoverplot", session)

  observeEvent(unhover_event(), {
    hoverplotlyProxy %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("relayout", list(images = list(NULL)))
  })

  observeEvent(hover_event(), {
    hoverplotlyProxy %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("relayout", list(images = list(
        list(
          source = hover_event()$customdata,
          xref = "x",
          yref = "y",
          x = hover_event()$x,
          y = hover_event()$y,
          sizex = 20,
          sizey = 20,
          opacity = 1
        )
      )))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Result]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61496833/is-there-a-way-to-read-images-stored-locally-into-plotly/) you can find a follow-up question on how to use local images in this scenario.