# How to make interactive scatter plot with pop-up picture by using R and/or Python

Tags: python, r, plot, interactive, scatter

I want to make an interactive scatter plot.

Specifically, when I click or place my mouse pointer on a point, the corresponding picture should be visualized.

Data structure is composed of x, y, and file-path (picture).

I tried following code but it didn't work.

```
library(plotly);library(png)

tmp=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(1,2,3),
file_path=c('C:/Users/osj118/Pictures/brain_illustrator.png',
        'C:/Users/osj118/Pictures/Cap 2021-05-17 12-32-24-509.png',
        'C:/Users/osj118/Pictures/brain_illustrator.png')
)
tmp %>% plot_ly() %>% add_trace(x=~x,y=~y,z=readPNG(~file_path))

Error in path.expand(source) : invalid 'path' argument
```

The below figure is what I want to make.

It is ok for me to use python code.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445198/displaying-image-on-point-hover-in-plotly) has been asked before. Answer in this question and other sources such as [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/displaying-image-on-point-hover-in-plotly/9223) suggest that there is no easy way to do this *just with plotly*. However, you can use it with shiny to create the custom hover images, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61497919/4938484) for example.

If you are open to using python as stated in the question, there is a simpler way to do this as below ([Source](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#custom-tooltip)):

```
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, output_file, show

output_file("toolbar.html")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[1, 2, 3],
    imgs=[
        'C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\pic.png',
        'C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\pic.png',
        'C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\pic.png',
    ],
))

TOOLTIPS = """
    <div>
        <div>
            <img
                src="@imgs" height="200" alt="@imgs" width="200"
                style="float: left; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;"
                border="2"
            ></img>
        </div>
    </div>
"""

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tooltips=TOOLTIPS,
           title="Mouse over the dots")

p.circle('x', 'y', size=20, source=source)

show(p)
```

Here pic.png could be the brain image you like to be using.